# r case_when, arrange and %like%

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data:

```
library(dplyr)

d <- tibble(
region = c('West Duns', 'West Alpha', 'East fun', 'East Hull',
         'Jess One', 'Jess Two'),
 figures= c(5, 7, 4, 8, 7, 6))
```

I would like the data to be arranged to look like this:

```
 d <- tibble(
   region = c('Jess One', 'Jess Two','West Alpha', 'West Duns' 
            'East Fun', 'East Hull'),
figures= c(7, 6, 5, 7, 4, 8))
```

And I know that I can do this using:

```
 d %>%
 arrange(factor(.$region, levels = c('Jess One', 'Jess Two','West Alpha', 
'West Duns' ,'East Fun', 'East Hull'))) -> d2
```

But what happens when I have really long data meaning it would take ages to type out every factor?
  I would like to use `case when` and `%like%` within the argument. So it would be something like this:

```
 d2 %>%
 arrange(factor(.$region, case_when (levels = c(%like% "Jess", %like% 
 "West", %like% "East"))) -> d2
```

So the factors are arranged by the first word given in the statement, and then are arranged alphabetically by the second word in the factor. I think the alphabetical ordering would occur naturally, so it's more how to use the `case_when` and `%like` arguments that I need help with.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option using `stringr::word` and `forcats::fct_relevel`

```
library(tidyverse)
d %>% group_by(reg=word(region)) %>% ungroup() %>% 
      mutate(reg_fac=fct_relevel(reg,'Jess','West','East')) %>% arrange(reg_fac)
```

We can short above to

```
library(tidyverse)
d %>% arrange(fct_relevel(word(region),'Jess','West','East')) 

# A tibble: 6 x 2
   region     figures
    <chr>        <dbl>
1 Jess One         7
2 Jess Two         6
3 West Duns        5
4 West Alpha       7
5 East fun         4
6 East Hull        8
```

Using `base::factor`

```
d %>% dplyr::arrange(factor(gsub('(.*)\\s.*','\\1',.$region), 
                            levels = c('Jess','West','East')))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d %>% 
  arrange(max.col(outer(region, c('Jess', 'West', 'East'), startsWith)))

# # A tibble: 6 x 2
#   region     figures
#   <chr>        <dbl>
# 1 Jess One         7
# 2 Jess Two         6
# 3 West Duns        5
# 4 West Alpha       7
# 5 East fun         4
# 6 East Hull        8
```

The `outer` of `region` and your names vector using `startsWith` gives a matrix whose i-j element is `TRUE` if `region` i starts with name j. Then `max.col` gives the index of the first column with `TRUE` for each row, i.e. the index of the element of your names vector the given region element starts with.

If you want to search the whole string instead of just the start you can replace `startsWith` with `Vectorize('%like%')`.